# Why ng-pattern is evaluated when the input field is disabled

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern

Why does angular evaluate a pattern when the input field is disabled. 
It should behave the same way as it does when the input field is hidden?

Check this fiddle,
[Fiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/JanakiSathya/438h4gzz/)

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="PatternTestCtrl">
        <form name="ngform">
            <label for="phone">Change the text to match the placeholder:</label><br/>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkValue" />
            </div>
             used ng-pattern <input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="phone" ng-pattern="/^\d*$/" ng-disabled="!checkValue" maxlength="12" placeholder="555-555-5555"/>
            <div>Pattern validity : {{ngform.phone.$valid}}</div>
            <br>
            <div>
                used ng-if : <input type="text" name="dummyNum" ng-pattern="/^\d*$/" ng-model="dummyNum" ng-if="checkValue" />
            </div>    
        <div> ng-if input box validity : {{ngform.dummyNum.$valid}}</div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Attached images for reference
[image: input field is active]

[image: when it is disabled]

Comment: it gets evaluated even when the field is hidden... can you setup the pluker showing that it does not get evaluated when hidden using ng-show/ng-hide, it wont get evaluated only if you are using ng-if to show/hide the field

Comment: I meant ng-if only. ng-show or ng-hide it gets evaluated.

Comment: Maybe you could add some code and tell us what bother you in the result.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-if` removes the element from the dom, hence the `ng-pattern` does not get evaluated.

`ng-show/ng-hide`, just make the element invisible, hence `ng-pattern` would still get evaluated.

`ng-disable` and `ng-pattern` are different directives, why should their functionality be intermixed.

We do in our app actually fire evaluations even on disabled fields. So I really do not see the reason why the two should be intermixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But disable simple means it is not valid and cannot be edited. Hence evaluating a pattern in such case doesnt make sense

Comment: disable means cannot be edited, agreed!, disable mean `not valid` cant agree!!! ng-disable dynamically disables the field, please understand that the field might be editable before and might need the pattern for the user input validation

Comment: yes only when it is active you need a pattern, when it is disabled why do we need it? Also if it is disabled (in my case) will not be using the data in the field.

Comment: why should ng-pattern worry about ng-disabled.. or as you go.. why should ng-min, ng-max, ng-**** worry about ng-disabled, SOC, one directive one job. if you want something custom, extend the directives..